# Access custom metadata through global variables

Tags: visualforce, custom-metadata

It's common to get at metadata around a custom object using the common `$ObjectType` global variable.

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label}
```

Can the same be accomplished with custom metadata to get its label or fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation does not state that you can access custom metadata via formulas, so it's pretty safe to assume that you cannot do so. For Visualforce, you could use Remoting or Remote Objects, and for Apex Code, you can use regular SOQL.

Comment: you can access via formula:  `$CustomMetadata.CustomMetadataTypeAPIName.RecordAPIName.FieldAPIName`. 

Unfortunately the same syntax does not work in VF pages

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_formula_fields.htm&type=0

Answer (score 2):

**I have some new information**

I know this works (API 41):

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{! $ObjectType.Your_custom_metadata_type__mdt.KeyPrefix }/e" target="_blank">Your Custom Metadata Settings</apex:outputLink>
```

As does this:

```
{!$ObjectType.Your_custom_metadata_type__mdt.Fields.DeveloperName.Label}
```

In **formulas** it's different:

```
$CustomMetadata.MetadataObjectName__mdt.YourDeveloperName.FieldName
```

eg: `$CustomMetadata.Links__mdt.Google.Url__c`

eg: `$CustomMetadata.Links__mdt.Facebook.Url__c`

Note no `{!}` in the above example (for formulas and things like url buttons)

So yes, you can use globals to access your Metadata type records in the same way as normal objects.

Comment: But still it only access metadata of "metadata" definition like field name, key prefix not the custom metadata record.

Comment: Actually, no, you can access the records as shown above.